# how can i use a dropdown menu to alter a value in SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

at present i have 2 pages that show tables of user information. the only difference in the 2 pages is a value in the SQL query. what i am wanting to do is have just a single page and use a dropdown menu to select which of the results i want to show.

i currently have:

page1.php

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>level</th>
</tr>
<?php
try {

    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT username, level, FROM members WHERE level < 5 ORDER BY username');
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['username'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['level'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
</table>
```

page2.php

```
 <table>
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>level</th>
</tr>
<?php
try {

    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT username, level, FROM members WHERE level > 4 ORDER BY username');
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['username'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['level'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
</table>
```

the difference being '< 5' and '> 4'.

how is it possible to set these 2 values as options in the dropdown menu, and condense to just a singular page?

Comment: Create a function and call it with certain parameters

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding of what gets executed on the server and the client. have a change of the dropdown return to the server and then use the dropdown value. So put the dropdown in a form and submit the form.

Comment: i think i understand, would a switch statement of the 2 queries work here, with the case being equal to the dropdown value - iv never used switch statements to perform SQL queries so unsure if this is an 'ok' approach.

Answer (score 0):

considering you will have a form using POST containing a select, you can do this:

```
// first the select
// TODO: enclose this in a form directed towards your php script
<select name="choice">
  <!--here two options with your desired values-->
</select>
<input type="submit" value="show rows">
```

then catch that value before your first `<table>`

```
$choice = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"choice",\FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

so that you can provide it to the function which will operate your sql:

```
function makeRows($choice) {
  switch ($choice) {
  case "1":
    $where = "level > 4";
    break;
  case "2":
    $where = "level < 5";
    break;
  default:
    throw new \Exception("that choice was not defined");
  }
  $stmt = $db->query('SELECT username, level, FROM members WHERE '.$choice.' ORDER BY username');
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['username'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['level'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }
}
```

you must be careful when doing sql based on a result from external input to never actually concatenate direct input into your sql. See how I "whitelisted" the sql which will be executed.

### how to use it:

```
// here put the form you've made containing the select
<table>
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>level</th>
</tr>
<?php
$choice = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"choice",\FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
try {
  makeRows($choice);
}
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
</table>
```

be sure to include the function definition in your script...